# How to remove a specific parameter in MySqlCommand?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying the parameter called `@idp` from my parameters list. In particular I've the following code:

```
Using dbCon As MySqlConnection =Connection()

dbCon.Open()

query = "INSERT INTO user (id_users, GUID)
                                       VALUES(@idp, @guidp)"

 MyCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, dbCon)

MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", 4) 'Parameter to replace in the next time
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guidp", GUID) 

... There is other parameter here I reduce in this example

MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idp", 5) 'Should replace the @idp but doesn't
Sync(MyCommand)

End Using
```

Now my query is just an example, I've a very long list of parameters so I don't want create redundant code. My application perform the insert in a local db and in online db. In the `Sync` function I pass the `MyCommand` as parameter and use `.Clone` for replicate the exact query in the online db. The problem's that in this specific case I've a constraint on this table, so I can't use the `LastInsertedId` of the query executed in the above code. For avoid this situation I've save a global variable that can be used in any class, this variable is used in the replaced parameter, but here for show what I want to achieve I just replace the variable name as `5` value, here:

```
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idp", 5)
```

How I can replace the parameter `@idp` with my `5` value instead of `4` without execute a `.Parameters.Clear` and redeclare all the parameters already use?

If something is unclear, tell me and I'll explain.

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. If you dont need `@idp`, dont add it, DbCommand objects are pretty specific to an operation and a database and are not means to be reusued over and over.  It seems to me that a method which returns a DbCommand object might be helpful: it could populate all the common params leaving the `Synch` code to add one or 2 for DB`; then create a new one for DB2 where you fill in the ones specific to  that one.

Comment: I need it for a previous use, but in the next query (displayed in my post) I need to use the last inserted id of the second db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). If you create parameters you can use `Remove` to exclude one without `Clear()`.
(caveat: I don't use MySQL so this syntax may not be exact)

```
MySqlParameter parUserId = new MySqlParameter("@user_id", MySqlDbType.Int32);
parUserId.Value = 5;
MyCommand.Parameters.Add(parUserId);
later....
MyCommand.Parameters.Remove(parUserId);
```